# Unusual Physical memory usage when huge number of bitmap images are created and saved as one bit per pixel image

Tags: c#, memory-management, bitmap, out-of-memory

I am trying to create large number of 1 bit per pixel bmp image from base 64 string and saving. As per the requirement a very huge number of images being created in a short period of time( an average of 50,000 to 1,00,000 in a short duration). I am using the below code.

```
  public void CreateoneBppImageAndSave(String base64ImageString,String ImagePathToSave)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64ImageString);

        System.Drawing.Image img = byteArrayToImage(byteArray);
        Bitmap objBitmap = new Bitmap(img);

        BitmapData bmpData = objBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, objBitmap.Width, objBitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
        Bitmap oneBppBitmap = new Bitmap(objBitmap.Width, objBitmap.Height, bmpData.Stride, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed, bmpData.Scan0);

        oneBppBitmap.Save(ImagePathToSave, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        img.Dispose();
        objBitmap.Dispose();
        objBitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        oneBppBitmap.Dispose();
    }

    private Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
        {
            return Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
```

Here the physical memory usage going very high. Usually the images are generated with size of 200x200 to 754x1024 . After certain duration physical memory usage reaching to the extreme and **out of memory exception** is being thrown.The physical memory is getting increased by 0.01 GB by every 5-10 seconds. Please help me to **optimize the code in terms of memory usage**.

Comment: Why are you manually calling `Dispose()` and not using `using` statements?

Comment: I am already disposing whatever objects possible to dispose by explicitly calling dispose on them.

Comment: is there any benefit over having disposable 'using' on object.dispose()

Comment: Should you not be calling `UnlockBits` on`objBitmap` ?

Comment: Per your correction, you call `UnlockBits` after you dispose, is that another typo or is that what you are really doing?

Comment: Edited as the actual code I am using `objBitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData)`. but wrongly posted in the question.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain is right, you need to unlockbits before you dispose. Once you have disposed you will no longer be able to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `LockBits` on `objBitmap` however you call `UnlockBits` on `oneBppBitmap`. You should be calling unlock on the same object you called lock on.

As for `using` statements like I mentioned in the comments, a using statement turns this

```
using(SomeType obj = new SomeType())
{
   // Some code
}
```

in to the equivalent of this

```
SomeType obj = new SomeType())
try
{
    // Some code
}
finally
{
    obj.Dispose();
}
```

That guarantees that even if a exception is thrown in `// Some Code` the dispose action will still happen. Your code, as it is right now, will not dispose any of its objects if any of your functions between the creation and dispose throws an exception.

Here is a re-written version with all the corrections I mentioned plus a few others..

```
public void CreateoneBppImageAndSave(String base64ImageString,String ImagePathToSave)
{
    byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64ImageString);

    using(Image img = byteArrayToImage(byteArray))
    using(Bitmap objBitmap = new Bitmap(img))
    {    
        BitmapData bmpData = objBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, objBitmap.Width, objBitmap.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
        try
        {
            using(Bitmap oneBppBitmap = new Bitmap(objBitmap.Width, objBitmap.Height, bmpData.Stride, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed, bmpData.Scan0))
            {        
                oneBppBitmap.Save(ImagePathToSave, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            //put the unlock in a finally to make sure it happens.
            objBitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** If this really is in your code

```
objBitmap.Dispose();
objBitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

That is the source of your problem, you should not call any methods on a class after you dispose. That is another benefit of `using`, you can't call methods late because the variable goes out of scope when you leave the `using` block.

Comment: oops. the code i mentioned was wrong. The real code is objBitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);. I am editing the question. Please excuse me on this.

Comment: +1 for your suggestion. But in the actual code I am unlocking bits on the object in which I had locked the bits. Is there any other suggestion to get a fix for the issue?

Comment: @amesh see my updated version, do you still get your problems if you rewrite it like I did, you may be getting a exception you are silently swallowing higher up the call stack and `Dispose` and `UnlockBits` may never be called.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I will try this and revert.

Comment: I checked the code, it doesn't have a method call on the object after dispose call.

Comment: Well, your example code does and we only have your example code to work off of.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. Sorry to tell you that It does not give much improvement on the same it seems. Memory keeps gradually increasing. Once in a while decreasing also, but not in a notable amount. Is there any memory leak related to C# bitmap class? Thanks

Comment: One more thing I noticed, when I am stopping the application which is running directly from visual studio, There is a big fall in terms of memory usage. Can I think like the issue is due to some other factor in the application? But the above is the major part of the code which the application being executed continuously.

Comment: @amesh These memory numbers, are you getting them while running with the debugger attached? The debugger greatly effects how objects are removed from memory, Also are you getting OutOfMemory exceptions or is it just you think it "uses a lot of memory" and want to reduce it?

Comment: When I ran the code individually from the exe I encountered this issue. But I am trying to reproduce by running the code from visual studio environment. That's my mistake. Now I need to check the code by running release mode exe again. Thanks